# Windows Domain Authentication while Disconnected

Tags: active-directory, authentication, ldap, windows-authentication

Is there a way to use domain authentication on a local machine when the machine is disconnected or the network is down? Local cache is not an option.  It will be a user that has never logged into this particular machine before. Looked at Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services. Wasn't sure if the directory could be replicated to the machine, then have the machine use a local directory.

Comment: Windows caches the AD authentication credentials for a period of time.  Allowing a user to logged into their machine if the AD domain server happens to be unresponsive.  If local cache is not possible then what you want is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No.

Windows needs *some* method of authenticating a logon attempt. For domain accounts, the *only*  ways to do this (in order of preference) are:

1. Contact a DC, which requires a network connection
2. Use locally Cached Credentials (if available)

In your question you have ruled both of these options out. **In this case it's impossible to logon with a domain account.**

---

There is one "alternative" scenario, though I offer this only for the sake of being technically thorough. I'd drop a client in a heartbeat if they asked me to do this...

**Give the user a domain controller.**

Yes, it's a horrible idea (so don't do it), but *technically* it would enable you to logon the machine 1) with a domain account, 2) that's never logged on the system before, 3) without a network connection.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer.  That's what I wanted to know.